# SELECT with a SUM condition

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a query that selects all `users` where the `SUM` of their transactions is greater than `25`.
I have this query:

```
SELECT users.uid, SUM( transactions.credits_earned ) AS total
FROM users, transactions
WHERE users.uid = transactions.uid AND ????
GROUP BY users.uid
```

I tried to use the alias `total` and the `SUM` itself directly in the condition but obviously it didn't work (and makes sense why). Do you have any idea how to do it keeping the query simple?

Thank you,
Diogo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT users.uid, SUM( transactions.credits_earned ) AS total
FROM users INNER JOIN transactions
ON users.uid = transactions.uid 
GROUP BY users.uid
HAVING SUM(transactions.credits_earned) > 25
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any advantage on using the `INNER JOIN` in this case?

Comment: It is the same in this case, but better for readibility. Also it is more consistant, once you start using *LEFT/RIGHT/CROSS JOINs*

Comment: astander is right. Also, some older dialects of SQL were not able to recognise that the WHERE form is in fact a join and thus WHERE queries could be very slow. Most modern SQLs are cleverer now.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
SELECT users.uid, SUM( transactions.credits_earned ) AS total
FROM users, transactions
WHERE users.uid = transactions.uid
GROUP BY users.uid
HAVING SUM( transactions.credits_earned ) > 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the HAVING clause